# Why installing the i386 version of a package triggers removal of the x86_64 version?

Tags: package-management, 32-bit, gcc

I found a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630775/why-does-the-installation-of-a-32-bit-package-remove-64-bit-packages), but the answer is not completely clear to me.

Why installing the i386 version of a package triggers the removal of the x86_64 version (and viceversa)? I see those are placed in their respective directories in /usr/lib/*arch*.

For instance, this is what happens on my system:

```
sudo apt install libicu-dev:i386 -V
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
   icu-doc:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   libicu-dev (57.1-5ubuntu0.1)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libicu-dev:i386 (57.1-5ubuntu0.1)
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 24.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

This is a problem as icu libs for the x86_64 arch are removed from the system, but I still need those.

Actually it seems this operation does not remove the libs completely, but it removes the .so files, which makes any link fail. To complete the build I need to install again the one that is missing.

I see that there may be a clash of the header files, maybe that is the reason? Why weren't those placed in separated directories according to the arch like it is done for the libs? As a matter of fact, it seems like it is impossible to build for i386 and x86_64 independently without having to switch the libs every time, which is pretty uncomfortable.

Someone who can explain this situation?

Comment: Did you first run  `dpkg --add-architecture i386` ?

Comment: Yes, without it apt could not even find libicu-dev:i386.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this is probably a bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=837898.